# Replace or remove multiple backslashes with 1 printed pair

Tags: r, stringi

How can I replace multiple backslashes with a single one?  I know that in a string a single backslash is represented with `\\` as demonstrated here:

```
nchar('\\')
[1] 1
```

So I want to replace replace all the backslashes in this string: `'thre\\\\fd'` with one (prints as two) and when wrapped with cat will produce: `thre\fd`.  I thought the **stringi** package has a way to do this easily but can't figure out how.

### MWE (not correct output)

```
cat(gsub('\\\\', '\\', 'thre\\\\fd'))
## threfd
```

### Desired Catted Output

```
thre\fd
```

Comment: Using `fixed = TRUE` is getting the output i.e. `cat(gsub('\\\\', '\\', 'thre\\\\fd', fixed = TRUE))#
thre\fd`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `fixed = TRUE` argument, we get

```
cat(gsub('\\\\', '\\', 'thre\\\\fd', fixed = TRUE), '\n')
#thre\fd 

cat(gsub('\\\\\\', '\\\\', 'thre\\\\\\fd', fixed = TRUE), '\n')
#thre\\fd
```

Answer (score -2):

If all strings have the same number of slashes, this is a very simple gsub:

```
x <- "test\\\\123"
gsub("\\\\","\",x)
output: "test\123"
```

Comment: Try your code...it does not work as the parser thnks you're escaping the double quote in the replacement.